# when creating a 3 lists of information 2 of the list turn out as expected but the email list the final list ends up with all the same information

Tags: python-3.x, list

the script this part of is to go through the entire email inbox and find any emails that mention one of the key words. It then puts Name, Email address and company into 3 lists. then at the end adds them to a pandas data frame to print to csv file at the end. The problem i am having is that the Name and company lists and columsn are acting as expected but the email address does not seem to be following the behaviour set out and the final list ends up being all the same item.  i am not sure what is causing it write over the entire list with the same item and then for all items that come afterwards

what i was expecting was

```
123@ABC.com 
234@boo.com 
info@example.com
```

what i get

```
123@ABC.com 
123@ABC.com 
123@ABC.com
```

heres the actual code

```
import email
import imaplib
import re
import pandas as pd
EMAIL = "email"
PASSWORD = 'password'
SERVER = "imap.example.com"

sender_list = []
sender_names = []
Sender_company = []
Sender_phone = {}
x = 0 
y = 1
# connect to the server and go to its inbox
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SERVER)
sock=mail.socket()
timeout = 60 * 20 # 5 minutes
sock.settimeout(timeout)
mail.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
# we choose the inbox but you can select others
mail.select('inbox')

# we'll search using the ALL criteria to retrieve
# every message inside the inbox
# it will return with its status and a list of ids
status, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
# the list returned is a list of bytes separated
# by white spaces on this format: [b'1 2 3', b'4 5 6']
# so, to separate it first we create an empty list
mail_ids = []
# then we go through the list splitting its blocks
# of bytes and appending to the mail_ids list
for block in data:
    # the split function called without parameter
    # transforms the text or bytes into a list using
    # as separator the white spaces:
    # b'1 2 3'.split() => [b'1', b'2', b'3']
    mail_ids += block.split()

# now for every id we'll fetch the email
# to extract its content
for i in mail_ids:
    # the fetch function fetch the email given its id
    # and format that you want the message to be
    status, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

    # the content data at the '(RFC822)' format comes on
    # a list with a tuple with header, content, and the closing
    # byte b')'
    for response_part in data:
        # so if its a tuple...
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            # we go for the content at its second element
            # skipping the header at the first and the closing
            # at the third
            message = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])

            # with the content we can extract the info about
            # who sent the message and its subject
            mail_from = message['from']
            mail_subject = message['subject']
            sender_formatted = mail_from.replace(">","").split("<")
            list_length = len(sender_formatted)
            if list_length != 2: 
                continue
            sender_email = sender_formatted[1]
            sender_name = sender_formatted[0]
            if sender_list.count(sender_email) > 0 : 
                continue

            # then for the text we have a little more work to do
            # because it can be in plain text or multipart
            # if its not plain text we need to separate the message
            # from its annexes to get the text
            if message.is_multipart():
                mail_content = ''

                # on multipart we have the text message and
                # another things like annex, and html version
                # of the message, in that case we loop through
                # the email payload
                for part in message.get_payload():
                    # if the content type is text/plain
                    # we extract it
                    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                        mail_content += part.get_payload()
            else:
                # if the message isn't multipart, just extract it
                mail_content = message.get_payload()
            words=["MF116","MF115","install","removal","U6","U16","U25","U40","U65","U100","meter","installed"]
            content= mail_content 
            # print(content)
            for word in words:
                result = re.search(word,content)
                if result : 
                    # print (f"search success: {word}")
                    sender_list.append(sender_email)
                    sender_names.append(sender_name)

                    company = sender_email.split("@")
                    company = company[1].split(".")
                    company = company[0]
                    Sender_company.append(company)
                    x += 1 
                    if x == 100 :
                        df = pd.DataFrame()
                        df['Contact Name'] = sender_names
                        df['Email Address'] = sender_email
                        df['Company'] = Sender_company
                        file_name = (f'contacts{y}.csv')
                        df.to_csv(file_name,encoding='utf-8')
                        y+1 

                
                    # print(sender_email,company, sender_name)
                    break
                else : 
                    # print(f"Search failed: {word}")
                    continue

            # and then let's show its result
            # print(f'From: {mail_from}')
            # print(f'Subject: {mail_subject}')
            # print(f'Content: {mail_content}')
            


mail.close()
mail.logout()
print(sender_email)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Contact Name'] = sender_names
df['Email Address'] = sender_email
df['Company'] = Sender_company

df.to_csv('contacts.csv',encoding='utf-8')

print("Searching has been completed")
```

i have tried an if loop to with an x counter to try to reduce the size of the list but this did not work. thank you in advance for the help

Comment: You should include your code in the question.

Comment: just edited to include code appologies it wasn't there